# Dispatch to action parameter sequence

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, dispatch, redux-actions

For example 
I have a action calling `crazyAction` it has three parameter second one and third one can be null but first one has to something as fallows;

```
crazyAction(firstParameter, secondParameter = null, thirdParameter = null){
      return{
         type:    CONSTANTS.WHATEVER,
         payload: {firstParameter, secondParameter, thirdParameter}      
      }
}
```

I should send the parameters by sequence when I want to dispatch to this, like;

```
    dispatch( uiActions.navigateToPage(firstParameter, null, thirdParameter));
```

So the question is if I want to send only thirdParameter without second one there is another option without null things on the middle?

like this one, How is that possible?

```
dispatch( uiActions.navigateToPage(firstParameter, thirdParameter));
```

Comment: nope.you cant do that

Answer (score 1):

With **[`Destructuring Assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)**,you can do something like this.

> **The missing params will come as a null, which will help you  to not pass params in order.**

```
    function crazyAction({ firstParameter, secondParameter, thirdParameter}){

      console.log(firstParameter, secondParameter, thirdParameter);
      //output "first"    null    "3"
    }
```

Define object holding the passed properties and call function.

```
const objParams = {
  firstParameter : "first", thirdParameter:"3"
};
crazyAction(objParams);
```

Working **[`codesandbox demo`](https://codesandbox.io/s/0o5459yzwl)**